# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2: Global Apps e Android/iOS App

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, requirements, visual-studio-cordova

I have installed Update 2 for Visual Studio 2013, but in the project list I don't say as create project for iOS/Android with Cordova. Operating system used are Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: The Update 2 for Visual Studio 2013 have introduced new features, but after I installed  the upgrade, a don't view the new functions.

Answer (score 4):

To build Multi device hybrid (Cordova tooling) apps with Visual Studio, you need:

- Windows 8.1
- Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 - Professional, Ultimate, or Premium

Install the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps extension from the download [page](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=397606)

You should ensure you also have:
Tools for Maintaining Store apps for Windows 8
Windows Phone8.0 SDK

You can add these by going to "Program and Features", selecting Visual Studio 2013 and clicking "Change", then "Modify" and then check the missing ones.

*Taken from the official documentation ([link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397716))

Comment: Can I do this on windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to install the Cordova integration for Visual Studio.

You can download it from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381

after that is installed, you get "Blank App (Apache Cordova)" for JavaScript and a similar one for TypeScript.

Comment: The Cordova integration requires *Windows 8*, for whatever reason... you can't install it on Windows 7.