# .csproj file unsupported in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

So I'm trying to do what I think is a very simple thing: generate a Windows Phone app with PhoneGap and open it in Visual Studio. On a totally fresh Windows installation (via Bootcamp), I've:

- Downloaded Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows (the very first download button: http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk)
- Created a PhoneGap Windows Phone app per the Getting Started guide.

However, every time I try to open the csproj file, I keep getting this error:

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
     - HelloWorld, "C:\BodBot\BodBot-PG\BodBot\platforms\wp8\HelloWorld.csproj"

No changes required
These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
     - HelloWorld, "C:\BodBot\BodBot-PG\BodBot\platforms\wp8\HelloWorld.sln"
```

No matter what I do. It works totally fine on Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone. I've tried it on VS 2013 for Desktop, and that doesn't work either. No clue what is happening here, and don't know even where to start to figure out what's wrong. I've Googled extensively to no avail; basically all instances of this error seem to have to do with previous version of VS. Pointing in any direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The first download is for 8.1 but your sample looks like 8.0? Not done WP8 programming so don't know if that's an issue

Comment: Oh, the directory? After searching around, it doesn't look like there are any changes that are necessary on PhoneGap's side to get a WP8 app to work on WP 8.1...or at least I haven't found anything indicator thing.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Update 2 wasn't getting installed correctly. I ended up installing Visual Studio and the Update 2 separately and Update 2 got installed successfully. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

To build Multi device hybrid (Cordova tooling) apps with Visual Studio, you need to have Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 - Professional, Ultimate, or Premium.

[Visual Studio 2013 Update 2: Global Apps e Android/iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628597/visual-studio-2013-update-2-global-apps-e-android-ios-app)